# Get facebook posts attachments return NullPointerException

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to get page posts attachments. This is a JSON which I try to get:

```
{
  "attachments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "media": {
          "image": {
            "height": 720,
            "src": "url",
            "width": 720
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "post_id"
}
```

My `@GET` request:

```
@GET("{post_id}")
fun getPostsAttachments(@Path("post_id") postId : String?,
                        @Query("access_token") authToken: String?,
                        @Query("fields") media : String?)
        :Observable<AttachmentsList>
```

Observable:

```
var getPostsAttachments: Observable<AttachmentsList> = facebook.getPostsAttachments(postId, "app_token", "attachments")
        getPostsAttachments.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeBy(
                        onNext = { result ->
                        imgUrl?.addAll(result.data)
                        Log.d("TAG_NEXT", "$result")
                    },
                    onError = { throwable -> Log.d("TAG_ERROR", throwable.toString()) },
                    onComplete = { Log.d("TAG_COMPLETE", "$imgUrl") }
                )
```

And it return `D/TAG_NEXT: AttachmentsList(data=null)` and `D/TAG_COMPLETE: null`.

How can I fix it ? Maybe my link request is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/attachment your path for the call is wrong. Try changing the Retrofit call annotation to `@GET("{post_id}/attachments")`.